# Angularjs provider: Resolve $http request before returning

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise, angular-providers

I have a provider that looks something like the following:

```
angular.module('myProvider', function(){
  var appUrl = ''
  this.setAppUrl = function(url){
    appUrl = url;
  }
  this.$get = ['$http', function($http){
    return {
      appAction: function(){
        $http.get(appUrl).then(function(response){
          //do stuff
        });
      }
    }
  }]
});
```

Currently the app sets the appUrl in a .config block based on constants generated as part of the build process using grunt ngconstant.

I'm trying to change the app over to loading the config file from a json file via $http. The provider now looks something like this:

```
angular.module('myProvider', function(){
  this.$get = ['$http', function($http){
    return $http.get('path/to/config.json').then(function(response){
      appUrl = response.appUrl;
      return {
        appAction: function(){
          $http.get(appUrl).then(function(response){
            //do stuff
          });
        }
      }
    });
  }]
});
```

This loads the config from the remote source, but has the unwanted side effect of returning a promise instead of an actual function. I've tried (unsuccessfully) to resolve the promise before returning the value from the provider. I don't want to change the rest of my application to expect a promise instead of a function to be returned. What's the best way to make sure that this method returns a function?

Comment: How would you expect this to work?  You are performing an async operation and the modus operandus is to use a promise.  You can't (and shouldn't) block on a promise, nor can you treat it like a synchronous call.

Comment: Keep the original code. When the app loads, load the config.json file then  setAppUrl with the response.appUrl

Comment: @Hoyen Unless I've missed something you can't use $http in a .config block

Comment: What is the context for the provider? If it can be made a route/state resolver, then yes, there is a way, because resolvers are injected as resolved promise values. If it can't, then no, there's no way.

Comment: @biagidp Can't you load the config.json and then call the config? Something like: $http.get('path/to/config.json').then(function(response){ myApp.config... 
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `appAction` method of the service returns a promise anyway; so we keep the value of `appUrl`: if it is non-null, we use it to retrieve our data. Otherwise we chain promises: first retrieve the configuration, then retrieve the real data. Something like the following:

```
angular.module('myProvider', function(){
  this.$get = ['$http', function($http){
    var appUrl;

    function retrieveTheRealData() {
      return $http.get(appUrl).then(function(response){
        //do stuff
      });
    }

    return {
      appAction: function() {
        if( appUrl ) {
          return retrieveTheRealData();
        }
        else {
          return $http.get('path/to/config.json').then(function(response){
            appUrl = response.appUrl;
            return retrieveTheRealData();
          });
        }
      }
    };
  }]
});
```